# Compact and Repair Database programmatically

Tags: c++, ms-access, compact-database

How can I call Access's Compact and Repair Database utility from within C++? I'm already using ADO and ADOX, so a solution using either of those would be handy.

Comment: Just to clarify, compact and repair are not independent operations. Since Jet 3.5 SR2 (c. 1998), there is no separate repair command, only a compact. Compact checks the integrity of any MDB it's run on and if it needs to be repaired does so. MS removed the separate repair command because running it on an undamaged MDB was sometimes corrupting them.

Comment: Another example of how an MDB can go corrupt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similiar to:

[How can I programmatically repair (not merely compact) an Access .mdb file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141810/how-can-i-programmatically-repair-not-merely-compact-an-access-mdb-file)

You can do this using `COM` to access the `JRO.JetEngine` object. There is an example in C# at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mdbcompact_latebind.aspx) which shouldn't be too hard to convert to C++.

UPDATE: Thanks to @le dorfier, here is an [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230501) with C++ example.

Comment: Yes, I saw that one there - however, I am asking about a C++ solution, which neither that question, nor any of the answers seemed to address.

Comment: Here's the same thing for C++
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230501
found with googling "c++ JRO.JetEngine"

Comment: @le dorfier: nice find! that one elluded me! :)

Comment: Any ideas on how to compact and repair an Access 2007 .accdb database file by code?