# How to automate Jet/ACE compaction? (Access DB)

Tags: ms-access, jet

I think the title sums it up fairly well.  I'll be working with a range of versions from the old 2003 all the way up to the most current releases.

It's a hosting company that has a lot of clients with access DB's.  What we're looking to do is to automate the compaction of them for performance/reliability reasons, but I'm finding it difficult to find any concrete information on how you would do this.

My preference is a PowerShell solution that can be kicked off remotely from a centralized location, if possible.  Barring that, writing a .Net or PS utility that gets placed on each server would work as well.

Does anyone have any good resources or knowledge on how best to go about doing this?  If I have to use slightly different things for different versions, that's ok.

Comment: Access has [command line switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) that can do this.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/141810

Comment: What happens when you try to compact a DB that's being used for some reason?  Does it fail?  Also, if I do use the Access CLI switches, I assume it does the right thing for all versions?

Comment: Access won't attempt to compact a database that is in use.  Does it do the right thing for all versions?  Only Microsoft knows for sure.  I would do some basic testing.